# Cleaning and sanitizing php code as per WP coding standard

Tags: php, wordpress, html-sanitizing

I have few lines of code which i need to clean up as per WP coding standard using the functions like esc_html, wp_kses() etc (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_kses/). That code generates a printing button on the post detail page. The problem is i can't figure out the correct way to use wp_kses function so as to show the button on the page.
Could anyone help me here? I am a beginner for php. Thanks in advance!

Code on the file

```
<!-- printer friednly link  -->
    <?php if(function_exists('pf_show_link')){echo pf_show_link();} ?>
```

Code i am trying to add which is not outputting any button

```
<!-- printer friednly link  -->
    <?php
    if ( function_exists( 'pf_show_link' ) ) {
        $allowed_tags = array(
            'strong' => array(),
            'a'      => array(
                'href'  => array(),
                'title' => array(),
            ),
        );
        echo wp_kses( $allowed_tags );
    }
    ?>
```

[image: the button which renders from the code]

Comment: You're not using the `wp_kses()` function correctly. Please go read [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_kses/#parameters) again and adjust your code accordingly.

Comment: Also, please share the contents of the `pf_show_link()` function so we can see what it does.

Comment: @cabrerahector - Thankyou for quick response. I am having difficulty in laying out the code as am completely a beginner for the code. Can you please modify that code and share. Thanks

Comment: The function outputs this code:-

`<div class="printfriendly pf-alignleft"><a href="#" rel="nofollow" onclick="window.print(); return false;" class="noslimstat" title="Printer Friendly, PDF &amp; Email" data-wpel-link="internal"><img style="border:none;-webkit-box-shadow:none; box-shadow:none;" src="https://cdn.printfriendly.com/buttons/printfriendly-button.png" alt="Print Friendly, PDF &amp; Email"></a></div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure you should use wp_kses here at all. If you are the one who generates that html output with function, you don't need to sanitize. Anyway, if you really want to, you must list **all** html tags you use (so also, `div`, `img`...) and **all** attributes inside those tags (`style`, `src`, `onclick`...). Try like this:

```
$allowed_tags = array(
    'div'    => array(),
    'img'    => array(
        'style' => array(),
        'src' => array(),
        'alt' => array()
    ),
    'strong' => array(),
    'a'      => array(
        'href'  => array(),
        'title' => array(),
        'rel' => array(),
        'onclick' => array(),
        'class' => array(),
        'data-wpel-link' => array()
    ),
);

echo wp_kses(pf_show_link(), $allowed_tags);
```